# What is the immediate lower number next to One in Double precision

Tags: matlab, double

What is the most immediate lower number next to number 1, in [double-precision number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) ? How to find that in MATLAB?

For instance, the next higher number next to positive number `X` can be find using `X+eps(X)`. But how to do that for an immediate lower number?

Comment: You can use bitget and bitset in combination. Starting at the least significant bit flip the value until you flip a 1.

Comment: that's interesting to know. I never knew the functions of bitget/bitset before.

Answer (score 1):

```
format hex # So that the difference is easy to see
X-eps(X)
```

appears to work just fine

Comment: Is 1-eps(0.5) not greater than 1-eps(1) ? and therefore the nearest and lowest number next to One?

Comment: The largest IEEE754 64-bit binary less than 1.0 is 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875

Answer (score 0):

use the code bellow ,B is most immediate lower number next to number 1 that is half of eps:

```
A = uint64(0);
bits=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0];
for i = 1: 64
    A = bitset(A, i, bits(i));
end
fileID = fopen('bits.bin','w');
fwrite(fileID, A,'uint64');
fclose(fileID);
fileID = fopen('bits.bin');
B = fread(fileID,1,'*float64');
fclose(fileID);
disp(B);
disp(1.0-B);
disp(eps(1.0))
```